# c generate temp config file with buffer for later usage in code

Tags: string, c

i want to create a temporary config file for my serial readers
an i think my code is not optimal 
is there a better way to detect the devices ?
has someone a hint to optimize my code

this config file will be read out later 
with fp = fopen(tempserv, "r");

and unlink(tempserv);

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define MOUSEPATH "/dev/serial/by-id"
/*
example content
usb-FTDI_FT232R_USB_UART_A4011SXX-if00-port0
usb-FTDI_FT232R_USB_UART_A4022SXX-if00-port0
usb-FTDI_FT232R_USB_UART_A4033SXX-if00-port0
usb-FTDI_FT232R_USB_UART_A4044SXX-if00-port0
*/
#define EASYSTRING "usb-FTDI_FT232R_USB_UART_"

int main (void){

DIR *dir;int i = 1;
struct dirent *ent;
dir = opendir (MOUSEPATH);
char tempserv[] = "/tmp/generate.conf-XXXXXX";
int fd;fd=mkstemp(tempserv);
char tempstr[512];
char devname[62];

if (dir != NULL){
<------>while ((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL){
<------><------>if (strstr(ent->d_name, EASYSTRING)){
<------><------><------>sprintf(devname, "%s/%s", MOUSEPATH, ent->d_name);
<------><------><------>int mtmp = open(devname, O_RDONLY);
<------><------><------>if((mtmp) > 0){
<------><------><------><------>sprintf(tempstr,"\n[reader]\nlabel = easymouse%d\nprotocol = mouse\ndevice = %s/%s\ndetect = cd\ngroup = 1\n\0", i++, MOUSEPATH, ent->d_name);
<------><------><------><------>write(fd,tempstr,strlen(tempstr));
<------><------><------><------>close(mtmp);
<------><------><------>}else{
<------><------><------><------>close(mtmp);
<------><------><------>}
<------><------>}
<------>}
} closedir (dir);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `else` branch does `close(-1)`. That's invalid.

Comment: What are you trying to optimize for?